# How to tell if an object was created with 'Object.create' or using literal syntax/'new' keyword

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to tell if an object was created using `Object.create()` or using the `new` keyword / literal syntax.  Because objects created with `Object.create()` do not take properties off the prototype property (they just sort of copy all the properties) and those made with the `new` and literal syntax take only the properties from the prototype property, it seems difficult to tell how an object was created.  For example:

```
function Meat() {};
var beef = new Meat();
var tuna = Object.create(Meat);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(tuna));//=> [Function: Meat]
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(beef));//=> {}

console.log(tuna.constructor.prototype);//=> [Function]
console.log(beef.constructor.prototype);//=> {}

console.log(tuna.prototype);//=> {}
console.log(beef.prototype);//=> undefined

console.log(tuna.__proto__);//=> object
console.log(beef.__proto__);//=> object

console.log(typeof tuna);//=> object
console.log(typeof beef);//=> object

console.log(Meat.prototype.isPrototypeOf(tuna));//=> false
console.log(Meat.prototype.isPrototypeOf(beef));//=> true
```

There doesn't appear to be any way to tell the method by which an object inherited it's properties.  Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt it, internally they'd be represented the same way by the JS engine. You might be able to replace implementations (e.g., AOP before/around advice) and do something that way if it's super-important. What's the purpose?

Comment: You've made a mess of things, and your goal is unclear. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Using `new` would make the returned object an instance of `Meat`, while `Object.create` wouldn't, but as noted above, what't the point ?

Comment: @amit If I've 'made a mess of things' you haven't explained how, so imo your comment is unclear.  The first sentence of my question clearly explains my goals:  "I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to tell if an object was created using Object.create() or using the new keyword / literal syntax." as these are different ways an object can be created.  If I'm being unclear I don't understand how and I don't understand why my question is a mess.  Please elaborate on your criticism of my question.  Thanks.

Comment: @adeneo I don't understand why anyone thinks I am asking what an instance of an object is.  I'm not asking what an instance of an object is.  My question was whether it is possible to tell if object B was created as an instance of Object A (using the new keyword or literal syntax, for example) or whether it was created not as an instance (using Object.create() as an example).

Comment: @Katgus - I accept your remark that my comment wasn't clear, I meant that the way you created the object is wrong, and that what you're later trying to compare didn't make sense. What I also asked is what is your goal? Why do you care how an object was created? (P.S. I'm fairly certain there's no failsafe method to do that)

Comment: @Amit I don't normally create objects like this, I was just playing around with JavaScript and trying to understand what is possible within the language.  I care about how an object was created so that I can understand code that I am looking at without any ambiguity.

Comment: I was just pointing out that in your code `beef instanceof Meat` would be true, as you've just created a new instance of that function, but `tuna instanceof Meat` would be false, as you haven't created an instance of Meat at all, which is why you get the result you're getting in the last two lines. As noted in the answer below, you need to pass in the prototype, not the object, and it shouldn't matter *how* the object was created, but *what* the object looks like.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.create` is a very generic object-construction operation. There's **no way to tell** whether an object was created with `Object.create` because there's no reliable feature of such objects (other than that they can't be native objects or Proxies).

And it is not true at all that `Object.create` “just sort of copies all the properties” — it just sets the `[[Prototype]]` (aka `__proto__`) reference to the value you provide. The only “copy”-like behavior is if you specify the optional second argument, but that takes property *descriptors*.

I note you've made one mistake that might be confusing the issue for you:

```
 var tuna = Object.create(Meat);
```

If you meant “make an object that is akin to the result of `new Meat()`”, then this is wrong. You want instead:

```
var tuna = Object.create(Meat.prototype);
```

because the parameter to `Object.create` is is the new object's *prototype*, not a *constructor*. The object you get by doing this will react the same to `instanceof`, `isPrototypeOf`, et cetera as `new Meat()`; it just won't have had the `Meat` constructor run on it, so it won't have any properties that such objects usually do.

Since your example constructor is empty, once you've fixed this, the two objects will have all the same responses to your various tests. This doesn't help you tell the difference (because you can't), but it should help you *not need to* tell the difference.

Comment: This answer is clearly the best, but just for clarification, when I said it 'just sort of copies all the properties' I said 'sort of copies all the properties' rather than 'copies all of the properties' because I didn't want to go off on a hairsplitting tangent of JavaScript nuances, I just wanted to focus on a specific question.

Comment: I figured this was the correct answer.  I guess I can create a function that goes over all the keys of the object and provides a best estimate.

Comment: @Katgus I understand that that isn't the main point of your question, but I mentioned it because it is useful to understand that _neither `Object.create` nor `new` do anything remotely like copying_.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reliably determine if an object was created using Object.create or new someFunction syntax. An object's `constructor` property is the most useful guide but does not guarantee the result. For example:

```
function Foo() {};
var foo = new Foo();
foo.constructor == Foo; // true
```

but `constructor` is not a read only property, so

```
Foo.prototype.constructor = Object;
foo.constructor == Foo;  // changes to false
```

Setting the prototype object of a constructor in its entirety also generally changes the constructor function, as inherited by objects created by the actual constructor, to  the constructor of the prototype:

```
Foo.prototype = {foo: "was here"};
var foo = new Foo ();
foo.constructor == Foo;   // false
foo.constructor == Object;  // true, the constructor of {foo: "was here"} is Object.
```

This last result, and the prototype chain structure of `foo` is now identical to that created by Object.create:

```
var foo = Object.create({foo: "was here"};
foo.constructor == Object;  // true;
```

but to dash hopes of this being useful, the constructor of an Object.create() returned object need not be Object:

```
var bar = Object.create( new Foo()); // the original Foo
bar.constructor == Object ; // false
bar.constructor == Foo;     // true;
```

More or less any combination of "key properties" can be set up using either constructor functions *or* Object.create. Some combinations might be contrived, but others will be by design or ease of coding.

`Object.create` does not leave detectable bread-crumbs in the prototype chain by **design**.